# ggplot2 plot title based on an iterating for loop variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to title each plot with the variable (k) I am using to iterate within a for loop:

```
> MyData
     Name Stat Year value
1  Site01  Max 2013 29.88
2  Site01  Med 2013 29.67
3  Site01  Min 2013 29.16
4  Site01  Max 2020 31.21
5  Site01  Med 2020 30.38
6  Site01  Min 2020 29.38
7  Site01  Max 2040 35.50
8  Site01  Med 2040 33.17
9  Site01  Min 2040 29.60
10 Site02  Max 2013 53.70
11 Site02  Med 2013 53.49
12 Site02  Min 2013 53.20
13 Site02  Max 2020 53.10
14 Site02  Med 2020 53.01
15 Site02  Min 2020 52.55
16 Site02  Max 2040 52.04
17 Site02  Med 2040 51.74
18 Site02  Min 2040 50.98

pdf("plots.pdf")
for (k in unique(MyData$Name)){
subdata <- subset(MyData, Name == k)

     print(ggplot(subdata, aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = Stat)) 
          + geom_line() + expand_limits(y=c(0,100)) + ggtitle(k))

}
dev.off()
```

The plots are generated just fine when using a string for `ggtitle()` (for example: `ggtitle("Name")`) or after removing `ggtitle()` completely.

Any suggestions for how to include the value of the iterator variable (k) as the title on each plot?

Comment: Please read (1) [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), (2) [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as (3) [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., provide some input data (e.g. an example set from R), so that your code can be copied, pasted and run.

Comment: I edited to include an example set of data (which actually works fine!) so there must be problem in my larger set of code

Comment: Well, if you can't reproduce the problem, it's going to be very difficult to help you. How is your data different than your sample? What exactly is the problem you are experiencing? Is there an error? Is anything plotted on any graph?

Comment: The problem remained while implementing my full set of code/input data. The problem was remedied after using `ggtitle(as.character(k))` as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: Instead of using the for-loop, why not go with `ggplot(subdata, aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = Stat, group=Name)) + geom_line() + expand_limits(y=c(0,100)) + facet_wrap(~Name)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What class are the data in MyData$Name ?

Try replacing `ggtitle(k)` with `ggtitle(as.character(k))` to ensure you're passing `ggtitle` a string.

Comment: Were you actually able to reproduce the original problem? Is your claim that `k` is numeric? The code provided by the OP seemed to work just fine for me. I'm not sure what problem this is fixing.

Comment: Apologies for the poor question. MyData$Name are strings

Comment: However, using `ggtitle(as.character(k))` allows for the full set of code to also run sucessfully, many thanks for this

Comment: @MrFlick Originally there was not an example of the data, so an incorrect class could have been the issue.

Comment: @user3830407 You should be careful in this case. Double check the class of each of `unique(MyData$Name)`, as you may have something unexpected there that "works" after coercion but may not be what you intended.

Comment: @conor Thanks for these words of caution. I have looked through the PDF output and all seems fine. The plot titles show the site names as I would expect. I will remain vigilant as I finalize the script.

Comment: @conor I have a follow up question. What if I wanted to name my plots based on another variable, for example `year` corresponding to k in the above case instead of the iterator k,  how would I do that?

Comment: @ManasiShah In the example above, OP uses unique values of the `Name` variable and `year` takes multiple values for each `Name`, so it wouldn't work as a title. If `year` was unique for each `Name` though, then in the way they've written the code above, you'd have to reference it like `ggtitle(as.character(unique(MyData$year[Name == k])))` or something similar. This style can get messy though, and I would recommend avoiding for-loops where you can in `R`. Using `tidyverse` syntax like a `group_by` on the `Name` variable would likely make things more clear. Feel free to post a new question too!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `paste()`, example:

```
ggtitle(paste(your_value))
```